# Error java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5

Tags: java, mysql

```
public int RegistrarPedido(Pedido ped) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO pedido (sala, Numero_mesa, total, usuario) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, ped.getSala());
        ps.setInt(2, ped.getNumero_mesa());
        ps.setDouble(3, ped.getTotal());
        ps.setString(4, ped.getUsuario());
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return r;
}

public int RegistrarDetalle(DetallePedido det) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_pedido (nombre, precio, cantidad, comentario, mesaID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, det.getNombre());
        ps.setDouble(2, det.getPrecio());
        ps.setInt(3, det.getCantidad());
        ps.setString(4, det.getComentario());
        ps.setInt(5, det.getMesaID());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return r;
}
```

Tengo este código para un sistema de reservas de pedidos en un restaurante, pero cuando llego a la sección de registro de pedido, me sale ese error:
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5

Comment: Te sugiero vuelvas a ejecutar tu código, el método RegistrarPedido al parecer no tiene ningún problema

Comment: Asegúrate de compilar tu proyecto antes de ejecutarlo... Java no ejecuta directamente los archivos donde tú escribes el código, si no los generados por el compilador. Es posible que estés ejecutando una versión diferente a la que estás viendo... En el código que pones en la pregunta no existe dicho error, así que debes estar ejecutando una versión anterior del código!